# How to use Azure DevOps Variable Group references in Terraform File

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure

I have a variable group defined in Azure Devops already with few variables. I want to use them in my Terraform configuration. Can anyone please tell me how do i refer the values in my Terraform file using the ADO variable group values.

I have the below code

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.0"
  backend "azurerm" {
    container_name       = "demo-generator-terraform"
    storage_account_name = "test-stor"
    resource_group_name  = "Test-Rg"
  }

  required_providers {
    azuread = "~> 1.0"
    azurerm = "~> 2.0"
    azuredevops =  { source = "registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops", version = "~> 0.0" }
  }
}



provider "azurerm" {
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  client_id       = var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  features {}
}



data "azuredevops_project" "demo-project" {
  name = "DemoGenerator"
}

data "azuredevops_variable_group" "default" {
  name = "demo-variable"
}

variable "client_id" {
  default = "290xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-bx25-xxxxxx4"
}



variable "subscription_id" {
}

variable "client_secret" {
 }

 variable "appserviceplan" {
}

variable "appservicename" {
}

variable "tenant_id" {
}
    


locals {
  custom_tags = {
    Environment = "Dev"
    Department  = "Finance"
    Owner       = "Self"
  }
}
```

## Resource Block

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "dev" {
  name     = "PULTerraform"
  location = "West US"
  tags     = local.custom_tags
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "dev" {
  name                =  
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.dev.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.dev.name}"
  tags                = local.custom_tags

  sku {
    tier = "Free"
    size = "F1"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_app_service" "dev" {
  name                = 
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.dev.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.dev.name}"
  app_service_plan_id = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.dev.id}"
  tags                = local.custom_tags
}
```

The variable group defined in my ADO is attached in the screenshot with few values marked as sensitive and hence they are masked

I would like to know how to define the name of the App Service Plan and the App Service in Terraform so that it references the already existing values in ADO Variable Group variables[image]

[image]

Just to add further, i have created a terraform.tfvars file and the contents of the file are shown below

```
client_id       = "290ca8c5-d706-4f3c-b525-cc8c51b63694"
client_secret   = __secret__
tenant_id       = __tenant_id__
subscription_id = __sub__
appservicename  = __appservicename__
appserviceplan  = __appserviceplan__
```

I also have a Replace Tokens task in my pipeline with the Target Files --> '**/*.tfvars' and Token Pattern --> **...** , but the task doesn't find anything and the output is given below of that task

```
2022-04-15T23:58:24.8107669Z ##[section]Starting: Replace tokens in terraform file
2022-04-15T23:58:24.8272887Z ==============================================================================
2022-04-15T23:58:24.8273218Z Task         : Replace Tokens
2022-04-15T23:58:24.8273453Z Description  : Replace tokens in files
2022-04-15T23:58:24.8273648Z Version      : 5.1.0
2022-04-15T23:58:24.8273848Z Author       : Guillaume Rouchon
2022-04-15T23:58:24.8275170Z Help         : [Learn more about this task](https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task/blob/master/ReplaceTokens/ReplaceTokensV4/README.md) (v5.1.0)
2022-04-15T23:58:24.8275655Z ==============================================================================
2022-04-15T23:58:25.1628403Z replaced 0 tokens out of 0 in 0 file(s) in 0.022 seconds.
2022-04-15T23:58:26.1647462Z ##[section]Finishing: Replace tokens in terraform file
```

Any idea what is happening here

Comment: Here it is working even with `targetFiles: '**/*.tfvars'`. According to the output of the Replace Tokens extension, it struggles already finding your `*.tfvars`file as it mentions __0__ files.

Comment: You **should not** store application-specific configuration in Azure DevOps. You are tightly coupling your infrastructure deployment process to your continuous delivery toolset.

Comment: @DanielMannSo where do you suggest we should put our variable values if someone is not using say Terraform Enterprise or Terraform Cloud. In TFE or TF Cloud, you have option to use TF Workspace variables which kind of replaces the ADO pipeline variables and is better managed. But what if i am using open source TF along with ADO, i cannot put my values in TFVARS right and get them checked to my Azure Repos as then it will be visible to everyone. So what is the alternative then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question can basically be generalized to "How to set the value of Terraform variables declared in the root module from Azure DevOps Variable Groups?"

[Terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#assigning-values-to-root-module-variables) list four possibilities to set the values of variables of the root module:

1. in a Terraform Cloud workspace,
2. via command line option,
3. as environment variable,
4. in a variable definitions file.

In the following I will elaborate on how to use the latter approach in Azure Devops.

In Terraform, you can specify values for variables of the root module in a [Variable Definitions File (.tfvars)](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files).
In your case this would look like as follows:

```
appservicename  = "appservicename" 
appserviceplan  = "PULTerraformplan"
tenant_id       = "your_tenant_id"
subscription_id = "your_subscription_id"
```

Now, in order to generate this `.tfvars` file from your variables group, you can use an Azure Pipelines extension called [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) from the market place. Just install it in your ADO org.

Next, add a template for the `.tfvars` file to your repository. In the following I will assume that your Terraform code resides in the `terraform` folder under the root of your repository. In this folder create the file `terraform.tfvars` with the following content:

```
appservicename  = "#{appservicename}#" 
appserviceplan  = "#{appserviceplan}#"
subscription_id = "#{subscription_id}#"
tenant_id       = "#{tenant_id}#"
```

Finally, extend your pipeline by referencing the variable group and by adding the `replacetokens` task:

```
variables:
- group: myvargroup

stages:
- stage: Test
  jobs:
  - job: Test
    steps:
    - task: replacetokens@5
      inputs:
        targetFiles: 'terraform/terraform.tfvars'
        encoding: 'auto'
        tokenPattern: 'default'
        writeBOM: true
        actionOnMissing: 'warn'
        keepToken: false
        actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
        enableTransforms: false
        enableRecursion: false
        useLegacyPattern: false
        enableTelemetry: true
```

Comment: It's worth noting for people who come across this answer in the future that although you *can* do this, it's a bad practice. Your infrastructure configuration should be decoupled from your continuous delivery toolset. Taking this approach makes it difficult to develop and test infrastructure changes locally, as well as results in a lot of pain if (...when...) your organization adopts a different continuous delivery toolset in the future.

Comment: I agree with Daniel at least partially. I would not recommend this approach in a bigger scale with numerous configuration variables, let alone with multiple environments. In those cases I would always externalize the config variables e.g. to a (Key) Vault, an Azure AppConfiguration or something similar.
In a simple setup like in the o.p., I consider it as acceptable to use a variable group.
@DanielMann Would you mind to share your suggestions where to store the config variables - for the sake of progress in knowledge...?